# Paperclip not saving photo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have looked through many similar questions and tried the solutions with no success.  I am using rails 3 and paperclip 3.  I have successfully installed ImageMagick as the tutorial on the paperclip github instructs.

In my model:

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/profile_photo_store/missing.png"
attr_accessible :photo
```

In my database I have added these columns:

```
:photo_file_name, :photo_content_type, :photo_file_size, :photo_updated_at
```

In my edit view:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => user_path, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <b>Add a Photo</b><br />
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div><br />
<% end %>
```

In my show view

```
<%= image_tag @user.photo.url(:medium) %>
```

I can tell that the photo is being sent because I see it going through via Firebug.  Yet the missing.png is still displaying.  Where does paperclip save the files?  What am I doing wrong.

Comment: add validates_attachment_presence as a start

Comment: ok, just tried that and got a form error message saying Photo can't be blank.

Comment: What does the log show wrt paper clip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't resolve this answer so I switched to carrierwave...afterwards I had a similar issue.  Reinstalled ImageMagick using package manager rather than build from source which solved it.  Apparently when built from the source, the bin file is saved in /usr/local/bin, which my rails app couldn't see.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3.2 the paperclip attachments are stored in your public folder public/system/users/[photo or avatar...]/... . You can check if they went through and were saved. I don't see any obvious error in your code. You can use this migration just to make sure:

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :photo_file_name, :string
    add_column :users, :photo_content_type, :string
    add_column :users, :photo_file_size, :integer
    add_column :users, :photo_updated_at, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :photo_file_name
    remove_column :users, :photo_content_type
    remove_column :users, :photo_file_size
    remove_column :users, :photo_updated_at
  end
end
```

And you can either remove the default photo code, or edit it to "/images/..." and create an image folder in your public folder, cause that's where paperclip is looking for the file. It seems that paperclip still is configured the 'old' way (all assets being in the public folder):  In user model

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "200x200>", :thumb => "60x60>" },
                         :default_url => "/images/default_:style_avatar.png"
```

If you want you can try to just write:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the strong parameter in the controller accepts :photo.